# Possession/Concept of My

Tags: developmental-psychology

Has any one studied whether are not in the predevelopment stage, or in any developmental stage whether the concept of possessing, or ownership comes into light in the psyche of an individual grasping they own something?

Comment: I had to read that three times before I got it.  It sounds like you are asking "When do humans first express or understand the concept of posession/ownership in the stages of development?"

Comment: @StevenJeuris Your absolutely right!